# Error in creating objects

Tags: grails

Hello I have these two classes

```
class Company {
    String company_name
    static constraints = {
        company_name  size: 3..20, unique: true, nullable: false
    }
    String toString() { return company_name}
}

class Job {    
    String job_name
    Company company  

    static constraints = {
      job_name  size: 3..20, unique: false, nullable: false
        company nullable: false
    }
    String toString() { return job_name}
}
```

and this method :

```
def register(String company_name,String job_name)
{
    def job = new Job(company : new Company(company_name : company_name), job_name: job_name)
    if (job.validate() && job.save())
    {
        redirect(url:"https//localhost:8080")
    }
}
```

I can create object for example `Company:nvidia`, `Job:worker` but if I try to create another position for the company `nvidia- Company:nvidia`, `Job:owner`  I get an error why?It is in the if clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `unique` constraint at the `company_name` attribute and your code is trying to create a new `Company` instance with every new `Job` instance.

You should do it like this:

```
def nvidiaCompany = new Company(company_name: 'nVidia').save()

def jobDesigner = new Job(company: nvidiaCompany, job_name: 'designer')
def jobDeveloper = new Job(company: nvidiaCompany, job_name: 'developer')
```

So you're reusing the `Company` instance. If you create just one `Job` instance in the code, you have to obtain the `Company` instance first:

```
def nvidiaCompany = Company.findByCompanyName('nvidia')
def jobDesigner = new Job(company: nvidiaCompany, job_name: 'designer')
```

Comment: it can be caused by 2 things. First is, that you use underscore in the attribute name (`company_name` instead of usual `companyName`). Second is, that it depends on your IDE, because these methods are dynamically added during the compilation/runtime, IntelliJ works usually good, not sure about Eclipse/STS, the Grails/Groovy support was quite insufficient last time